# Python equivalent for write in file like in shell

Tags: python, bash, shell, sh

Is there a way to write in file like in shell script but in python by doing something similar to this:

```
cat >> document.txt <<EOF
Hello world 1
var=$var
Hello world 2
EOF
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you are referring to the [here document](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) feature in bash. I don't think there is a direct equivalent in Python, but you can enter multi-line strings using `"""` (triple quotes) to delimit the start and end, e.g.

```
>>> long_string = """First
... Second
... Third"""
>>> print long_string
First
Second
Third
```

which you could then write to a file:

```
myFile = open("/tmp/testfile", "w")
myFile.write(long_string)
myFile.close()
```

and achieve much the same thing as your bash example.

Answer (score 2):

```
with open('document.txt', 'w') as fp:
    fp.write('''foo
{variable}
    '''.format(variable = 42))
```

Though you probably want to do several calls to `fp.write` (or `print`) for each line, or use `textwrap.dedent` to avoid whitespace issues, e.g.

```
with open('document.txt', 'w') as fp:
    print >>fp, 'foo' # in 3.x, print('foo', file = fp)
    print >>fp, variable
```

It's probably best to just read [the tutorial](http://docs.python.org/py3k/tutorial/index.html).